# Undefined symbols generated by Google Mobile Ads SDK

Tags: ios, swift, google-mobile-ads

I have removed and updated the repo several times and reinstalled the pods but it keeps coming back to the following errors:

```
ld: Undefined symbols:
  _kGADErrorDomain, referenced from:
      -[GADMAdapterAppfireworks getInterstitial] in AdapterAppTracker.a[arm64][2](GADMAdapterAppfireworks.o)
      -[GADMAdapterAppfireworks getInterstitial] in AdapterAppTracker.a[arm64][2](GADMAdapterAppfireworks.o)
      -[GADMAdapterAppfireworks getBannerWithSize:] in AdapterAppTracker.a[arm64][2](GADMAdapterAppfireworks.o)
      -[GADMAdapterAppfireworks onModuleFailed:error:cached:] in AdapterAppTracker.a[arm64][2](GADMAdapterAppfireworks.o)
      -[GADMAdapterAppfireworks onModuleFailed:error:cached:] in AdapterAppTracker.a[arm64][2](GADMAdapterAppfireworks.o)
      -[GADMAdapterAppfireworks setUp] in AdapterAppTracker.a[arm64][2](GADMAdapterAppfireworks.o)
      -[GADMAdapterAppfireworks setUp] in AdapterAppTracker.a[arm64][2](GADMAdapterAppfireworks.o)
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.  That is all there is in the logs that I have been able to determine.

Pod file snippet:

```
platform :ios, '14.0'

use_frameworks!

target 'CDLPractice' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks

  # Pods for CDLPractice
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Database', '~> 7.0.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Performance'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
  pod 'SwiftLint'
  pod 'ZendeskChatSDK'
  pod 'MBCircularProgressBar'
  pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 3.0.0', '< 4.0'
```

I removed google mobile ads completely and the program compiled.  Added back the pod file and immediately received the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_kGADErrorDomain", referenced from:
      -[GADMAdapterAppfireworks getInterstitial] in AdapterAppTracker(GADMAdapterAppfireworks.o)
      -[GADMAdapterAppfireworks getBannerWithSize:] in AdapterAppTracker(GADMAdapterAppfireworks.o)
      -[GADMAdapterAppfireworks onModuleFailed:error:cached:] in AdapterAppTracker(GADMAdapterAppfireworks.o)
      -[GADMAdapterAppfireworks setUp] in AdapterAppTracker(GADMAdapterAppfireworks.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (us
```

I created a completely new project; did a pod init.
Added: pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
and recompiled and it blew up again:

The following is the error:

```
ld: warning: search path '/Users/douglaspalme/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/rTest-cgwpukuijruepmhdmeuupomktnaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities' not found
ld: warning: search path '/Users/douglaspalme/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/rTest-cgwpukuijruepmhdmeuupomktnaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC' not found
ld: warning: search path '/Users/douglaspalme/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/rTest-cgwpukuijruepmhdmeuupomktnaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb' not found
ld: warning: search path '/Users/douglaspalme/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/rTest-cgwpukuijruepmhdmeuupomktnaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' not found
ld: warning: search path '/Users/douglaspalme/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/rTest-cgwpukuijruepmhdmeuupomktnaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/GoogleAppMeasurement/AdIdSupport' not found
ld: warning: search path '/Users/douglaspalme/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/rTest-cgwpukuijruepmhdmeuupomktnaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/GoogleAppMeasurement/WithoutAdIdSupport' not found
ld: warning: search path '/Users/douglaspalme/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/rTest-cgwpukuijruepmhdmeuupomktnaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/GoogleUserMessagingPlatform' not found
ld: framework 'FBLPromises' not found
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Clearly something is screwed up, I just cannot figure out what.  I tried to add that framework and it's not found.

Comment: Can you share the code where you are calling the methods associated with AdMob?

Comment: I have added the additional code